# How to cast Angular form data into a POST request that the server will accept?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, post, crud

Need to find a way to send data to server in a form that server accepts. The title and descriptions are being sent but not ratings. There will be more than two rating types.

The server's POST request body example that needs to be met:

```
{
    "title": "Test title",
    "description": "Test description",
    "ratings": [
        {
            "value": 2,
            "category": {
                "name": "difficulty"
            }
        },
        {
            "value": 5,
            "category": {
                "name": "story"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Angular component.ts review form using FormBuilder. User enters a 1-10 score for scores.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.reviewForm = this.fb.group({
    gameTitle: ['', []],
    gameDescription: ['', []],

    scores: this.fb.group({
      difficulty: [, []],
      story: [, []]
    })
  })
}
```

Angular component.ts submit form data via the service

```
onSubmit() {
  this.gameService.postReview(this.reviewForm.value)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.success = true;
    });
}
```

Angular API service.ts to post the data to server. How do I cast the ratings data below so that server accepts it. And how do I get the score values and names in ratings object.

```
postReview(reviewData: any) {

  const gameReview = {

    title: reviewData.gameTitle,
    description: reviewData.gameDescription,

    ratings: [{
      value: reviewData.scores.value,
      category: {
        name: reviewData.scores.key
      }
    }]
  };

  return this.http.post(this.API_URL, gameReview, httpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your http post looks kind of strange, there are not even headers included. A http post looks like this:

```
        var headers = new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type": "application/json" });
        this.http.post<LogAnswer>(url,
            {
                gameReview //your json Object
            },
            {
                headers  //your headers, depending on you backend you may include some
                         //more properties
            }
        ).subscribe(
            (val) => {
                //maybe get a token back from your backend
                console.log("it worked")
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("didnt work");

            }
        );
```

Furthermore I recommend using postman if you want to check if your api does really work and maybe which headers have to be send aswell. Let me know if it worked

Comment: Backend API tested and works. The headers are entered in `httpOptions` post parameter. I can send the data successfully if i enter in `ratings` array exact code as in the post request example shown at the top. The problem is that i want to add/map the values from the user data entered in FormGroup `scores` into the `ratings` array of the `postReview` method.

Comment: Try the way I Made the http requests.  The way how you initilize your json object looks fine. Have you ever debugged it? You sure That formGroup has on empty values?